# Google Analytics: How to tracking users when they visit the registration page but leave without registration?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-filters

using tag manager -> count the number of users who are visiting the registration page but without register, they leave this site or page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an event or an objectives on the thank you page or the page right after the registration.

Then you will have all visitors landing in the registration page.
And you will create a segment of users that did visit the registration page + realize the objective of reaching the page after or the event of user registration completed.

And you have both state available.